# Replace Visual Studio build system with an Extension

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-extensions

The ReSharper extension for Visual Studio enables you to click a button `Enable ReSharper Build` which ["overrides and replaces" the Visual Studio build system](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Building_Solution.html). After clicking this button, running any build action (right-click, ctrl-shift-b, build menu, etc) in Visual Studio appears to be "redirected" to ReSharper Build. Even Standard F5 and Debug are directed to ReSharper's build window and wait for ReSharper to build before running.

I'm interested in developing my own extension that replaces the Visual Studio build system with my own build system in the same way that I see this done with ReSharper. However, I'm not [finding any documentation on Visual Studio's extension API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019) that hints at how this can be done. I'm not surprised, as I don't think this is a standard thing to do by any means, but apparently it is possible in some way, because ReSharper has done it.

How can I write an extension that allows the user to click a button that replaces Visual Studio's build process with my own?

Comment: You could try to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243164/hooking-into-build-process-in-visual-studio).

Comment: Oh good find. That ended up leading me to [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS), which I think I can base my solution off of. I'll try to update back here when I've tested some things.